# How to compile regions in proportion table with CIs to report total proportion with CIs

Tags: r

My current table looks like this:

| Region | Diabetes | percentage | lower limit | upper limit | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 85 | 80 | 90 | 100 |
| 1 | 1 | 15 | 10 | 16 | 500 |
| 2 | 0 | 90 | 80 | 97 | 198 |
| 2 | 1 | 10 | 7 | 20 | 134 |
| 3 | 0 | 97 | 90 | 99 | 434 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 0 | 10 | 283 |

This is the code I used to create that table.

```
CIregion_prop <- dta %>%
   filter(!is.na(Diabetes)) %>%
   filter(!is.na(region)) %>%
   group_by(region) %>%
   count(diabetes) %>%
   mutate(perc =prop.table(n)*100,
   lower = lapply(n, prop.test, n = sum(n)),
   upper = sapply(lower, function(x) x$conf.int[2])*100, 
   lower = sapply(lower, function(x) x$conf.int[1])*100)
```

I want to transform the table to below. Organized by how many people are positive and negative in each region to look like this:

| Diabetes | percentage | lower limit | upper limit | N |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 85 | 80 | 90 | 732 |
| 1 | 15 | 10 | 16 | 917 |

---

### How can I transform my above code?

Comment: The first table is organized by region, while the second isn't. Please clarify the desired output, which seems different based on the text and the example given.

Comment: My desired output is the table in the bottom. When I organize by Diabetes in the group_by function, the percentage is 100% for both 0 and 1. Which is of course, not right, so I'm thinking that that is too simple of a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `dplyr::select()` to remove the region data and omit the `group_by()` step:

```
library(dplyr)

region <- sample(c(1,2,3), 1649, replace = T)
Diabetes <- sample(c(0,1), 1649, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(region, Diabetes)

CI.no.region_prop <- df %>%
  filter(!is.na(Diabetes)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(region)) %>%
  dplyr::select(Diabetes) %>%
  #group_by(region) %>%
  count(Diabetes) %>%
  mutate(perc = prop.table(n)*100,
         lower = lapply(n, prop.test, n = sum(n)),
         upper = sapply(lower, function(x) x$conf.int[2])*100, 
         lower = sapply(lower, function(x) x$conf.int[1])*100)
```

Comment: Yes! That did the trick!! Thank you!!!